# How can I create a custom loading image that spins?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-experience

I'm trying to create a custom loading image.
I used this [website](https://loading.io/animation/icon/) for create the gif from my svg but the output resolution is very horrible if you don't pay.

I would like to have this effect:

[image]

For now I have a custom Progress bar with a rotating image:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/updateProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading"
    android:indeterminateDuration="2000"
    />
```

loading.xml:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:drawable="@drawable/loading_image" >
</rotate>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: i'm using this library for animations: [LottieAnimations] (https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User an interpolator on your loading.xml to accelerate the initial animation and decelerate at the end.

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
```

Also you don't need to add a `Progressbar` for making it rotate. Just call

```
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.loading));
```

where your view can be almost any view (`ImageView`, for example).

Comment: And probably decrease the `android:indeterminateDuration ` to about `300`